# Mudar favicon para torná-lo um pouco distinto do usado no StackOverflow em inglês

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, big-7

Eu possuo a mania de abrir inúmeras abas ao mesmo tempo, e me deparei com uma confusão para encontrar a aba do SO em pt juntamente com outras abas do SO em inglês.

Seria interessante um pequeno detalhe, mesmo que mínimo no favicon, por exemplo: um pt bem pequeno no canto, uma bandeira, algo do tipo.

O que acham?

> Update: Tem um traço embaixo agora...

Comment: Pinta de verde e amarelo! (Falando sério, não.)

Comment: @bfavaretto haha, mas realmente, não. Acho o que o pt pequeno seria interessante. Se alguém tiver um editor de imagens e quiser se propor a exibir um exemplo. (:

Comment: O design do site ainda não foi finalizado. Vou falar sobre isso com o pessoal

Comment: Seria legal, mas acho que não seria possível escrever algo pequeno num favicon. São pouquíssimos pixels disponíveis...

Comment: Fiz algumas versões de favicon aqui utilizando o original do SO com "BR" escrito.  Essa questão continua em aberto, né? Se quiserem posso mandar como resposta aqui...

Comment: Não saquei qual é a do favicon novo, mas ja é uma diferença...

Comment: À propósito, @Gabe, não sei se é pq eu raramente espio o chat, mas sinto uma falta de feedback seu aqui. Não sei se é só com os assuntos que eu participo, mas em geral a impressão que dá é que você aparece, faz uma série de coisas e desaparece. Seria legal documentar as novidades aqui no Meta pra gente, acho (em geral, não só do favicon).

Comment: Concordo com o @Bacco, o 6 da resposta mais votada era bem mais intuitivo. E da opinião do feedback também.

Answer (score 5):

### Algumas variações para ajudar a pensar. Estão longe do ideal ainda.

1. Versão com bandeira: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so1.ico
   [image: ícone com bandeira]
   (Tem o problema de ser Brasil, e não PT. foi mais pra teste mesmo. Pelo mesmo motivo nem fiz versão verde e amarela do original.)
2. Versão com PT centralizado: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so2.ico
   [image: ícone com PT centralizado]
3. Versão com PT verde: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so3.ico
   [image: ícone com PT verde]
4. Versão com PT amarelo: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so4.ico
   [image: iícone com PT amarelo]
5. Versão com PT embaixo: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so5.ico
   [image: ícone com PT embaixo]
6. Versão com PT no topo à esquerda: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so6.ico
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
7. Versão com PT amarelo atrás do logo: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so7.ico
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Página de testes, para ver todos na aba: http://files.box.net.br/favicon_so0.htm

Sugestão: teste em vários browsers, e intercale em várias abas diferentes.

Os únicos que eu achei razoáveis foram o 6 e o 7.

Comment: Achei o 6 bem interessante!

Comment: @JCM é o melhorzinho no meu ver. Testando ele em várias abas intercalando com o original ele não polui tanto. O ideal é ver em vários browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui vai a minha sugestão, aliás, vão três sugestões (bem parecidas, só as cores mudam um pouco). Quem sabe a equipe do SO não acaba aproveitando, né?

[image: Minha sugestão]

Comment: O azul é mais legível que os outros por dar um contraste melhor com o laranja do logo.