# Logotipo do site

Tags: debate, status-pronto, design, layout

Há alguma intenção em mudar o logotipo do site? Não necessariamente agora, talvez quando sair do *beta*?

Não digo mudar o logo propriamente dito, mas sim *caracterizá-lo* de alguma forma, para diferenciar do SO original - vide aba de reputação no cabeçalho, onde ficam os dois logos iguais lada a lado. De repente trocar as cores para as das bandeiras dos países que falam português (e ativos no site) ou algum fundo transparente. Não sei, algo nesse sentido.

Para os moderadores: Há algum plano para isso?

Para o restante: Opiniões?

Comment: Eu não acho que devamos mudar o logo em si, afinal a proposta e o nome do site são os mesmos. Prefiro manter-lo como está. Mas concordo que ter os dois SOs abertos lado a lado confunde, seria bom ter algum elemento que diferencie o favicon, talvez um pequeno "pt" no canto.

Comment: Eu votaria por um PT, se fosse possível adicionar em um ícone tão pequeno.

Comment: Não to falando do favicon, to falando do logo em si. Até porque na minha opinião ficaria estranho um favicon diferente do logo.

Comment: Não acho que o logo deva ser alterado, "em Português" abaixo do logo está ótimo. Se mudasse o logo ficaria estranho, não é um site diferente, é o mesmo em outro idioma... Agora o favicon precisa de alguma distinção para não confundir na aba de reputação.

Comment: Não é duplicata, esta é sobre o logo e a outra sobre o favicon.

Comment: @bfavaretto logo, favicon, desenho, imagem.. tudo igual. Who cares? Importante é fechar a pergunta e contar um flag a mais no perfil ;)

Comment: Postei uma sugestão de logo lá na outra pergunta. Se esta for reaberta, movo a resposta para cá.

Comment: @bfavaretto tranquilo cara. Sem neurose. Valeu.

Answer (score 5):

Sou a favor de manter o mesmo logo. Creio que o "em Português" está bem visível na lista de opções, e pra não atrapalhar nas abas, [basta o favicon ter um indicativo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/22/mudar-favicon-para-torna-lo-um-pouco-distinto-do-usado-no-stackoverflow-em-ingle) (sem alterar o logo também).

Answer (score 4):

Uma sugestão que altera levemente o logo do SO com uma referência ao *til*, tão comum na nossa língua portuguesa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>A imagem acima é só para ilustrar a ideia, a execução foi nas coxas.</sup>