# Formatação das opções da pergunta está quebrada

Tags: bug, status-intencional, design, formatação

A formatação das opções de uma pergunta que foi editada e em simultâneo está com algum tipo de contagem de votação fica quebrada, principalmente devido às expressões em Português que ocupam mais espaço do que as originais em Inglês.

[image: Captura de Tela]

Penso que aqui só mesmo jogando com as dimensões dos elementos é que se consegue resolver a questão, visto que em relação às traduções realizadas, não restam dúvidas de que estão correctas.

Passar:

```css
.user-info {
    height: 35px;
    width: 185px;
}
```

Para:

```css
.user-info {
    height: 35px;
    width: 184px;
}
```

Já resolve o problema, ou seja, 1 pixel a menos na largura:

[image: Captura de Tela]

---

<sup>[Aceder aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/148/logotipo-do-site) à pergunta onde se pode verificar isto.

De notar que após a votação desaparecer, o problema deixa de ser visível.</sup>

Comment: O fix [desse bug](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1857/12) continua permitindo que a linha de ações continue quebrando, mas agora de um jeito mais organizado e bonito.