# Assinatura da pergunta a passar para a coluna direita do site

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout, formatação

No seguimento da questão já colocada sobre a [formatação da opções da pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/566/223) que se encontrava "quebrada", parece terem existido alterações na mesma área que causam o seguinte problema:

[image: Captura de Tela]

O tracejado a vermelho indica onde "deveria" terminar a coluna esquerda do site, contudo podemos verificar que existe um `overflow` da assinatura do autor de tal forma elevado que chega a ficar por baixo dos *widgets* na coluna direita.

**Nota:**

O problema pode ser visualizado na pergunta [Refatoração de função para remover pontuação, espaços e caracteres especiais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/858/223)

---

## Actualização em 2014-06-09

Em baixo captura de tela em Firefox 29.0 para Linux:

[image: Firefox 29.0 - Linux]

Podemos ver que temos todas as opções da pergunta no lado esquerdo, e é visível também o overflow no lado direito.

Em baixo captura de tela em Opera 12.16 para Linux:

[image: Opera 12.16 - Linux]

Podemos ver que no lado direito não temos overflow da assinatura, mas no lado esquerdo só uma das opções da pergunta está visível, faltam as restantes 5.

Comment: Acho que isso só ocorre com tem tem o privilégio de proteger perguntas, caso contrário o espaço disponível deve ser suficiente.

Comment: @bfavaretto Parece que sim, todavia, era preferível limitar o espaço das opções e quando necessário ter duas linhas ao invés de empurrar ao infinito a info da última edição e do autor para o lado.

Comment: Seria legal comentar os browsers envolvidos, aqui no Opera baseado em _presto_ isto não acontece. Não sei se já foi resolvido (já que a pergunta é "velha"), mas em todo o caso, achei melhor mencionar.

Comment: @Bacco Velha sim, resolvida não. Actualizei a pergunta com mais elementos.

Comment: @Zuul perfeito. Só pra complementar, no Windows o layout do Opera 12.17 fica parecido com o seu, mas com todos os 6 links.

Comment: Eu modifiquei o "moderador" da linha de ações para "mod". Vamos ver se resolve. Caso não dê jeito, vou enviar para os designers.

Comment: @Gabe Resolveu pra nós moderadores. Os usuários comuns que fiquem com o bug, hehehe! Falando sério, quem tem privilégios de 15k (3.5k aqui) enxerga um link "proteger" que está causando isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pior que nem pra gente consertou. To mandando pros designers

Comment: Ué @Gabe, pra mim funcionou, mas no limite: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Cri.png

Comment: @bfavaretto Pra mim a assinatura do Zuul tá uns 5 pixels pra baixo da lista de perguntas ainda.

Comment: @Gabe Eu ainda vejo tudo mamado :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Ainda mamado aqui _(usuário comum a comer Bugs)_ ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os itens no rodapé dos posts (opções, última edição e autor) estavam em uma só `<table>`, e isso quebrava o layout com o tamanho maior.

Agora, as opções do post (compartilhar, editar, fechar, etc) tem `display: inline-block` e, como é possível ver nesta mesma pergunta, pulam para a próxima linha se necessário e o alinhamento das assinaturas se mantém.

Segundo o Jin, não é a solução que ele gostaria mas é o que resolveu por enquanto.